# How can I get Fedora and Opensuse server edition?

Tags: fedora, opensuse

I want to get server edition for Fedora and Opensuse. I've visited their respective sites, but there is no specific server edition in the download section. So how can I get the server edition for Fedora and Opensuse?

Answer (score 2):

Fedora's server edition is provided by netinstall or "normal" install image. I think server version can't be installed from Live-cd. [From here](http://fedoraproject.org/en/get-fedora-options#formats) you can download netinstall-iso or normal iso. And when you are installing it, there is screen where you for example set server where installer downloads packages (netinstall), there is also option "Choose packages" or something similar. There you can choose option "server".

Answer (score 2):

As for OpenSUSE, [go here](http://software.opensuse.org/123/en) to get the net install version or the DVD, both suitable for your purpose.